# C- main segmentation fault, string problem - how to solve

Tags: arrays, c, string

my main function needs to collect array size from user and fill it with strings, to then send out to functions - my main appears to crash after recieving a single string - I believe the error is due to temporary_string - when it does work I get no indication the arrays actually enter the function and the output is the same as the input - I don't know why.

```
int main() {
    int n = 0, rule = 0;
    char* temporary_string="";
    printNumStringsInputMessage();
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printStringsInputMessage(n);
    char** arr_of_strings= malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
    {
        scanf("%s", temporary_string);
        arr_of_strings[l] = malloc((strlen(temporary_string) * sizeof(char)));
        strcpy(arr_of_strings[l], temporary_string);
        strcpy(temporary_string,"");
    }
    printRuleOfComparisonInputMessage();
    scanf("%d", &rule);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: It does work meaning after some tinkering with the code, albeit it does send warnings

Comment: yes I think it does, although it's theoretical and I'm not sure I would've been able to correct my program without specific attention

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change this value: `char* temporary_string="";`, it's constant and it's same as `const char* temporary_string="";`, this causes the segmentation fault.
use instead an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You must not modify string literals.

Instead of

```
    char* temporary_string="";
```

You should allocate an modifyable array like this:

```
    char temporary_string[102400];
```

It is also a good practice to limit the maximum size to read to avoid buffer overrun.

```
        scanf("%s", temporary_string);
```

should be

```
        scanf("%102399s", temporary_string);
```

if you use the above array. The maximum length is the length of array minus one because the laste element is for terminating null-character.

Also you must allocate also for terminating null-character.
This means that this line

```
        arr_of_strings[l] = malloc((strlen(temporary_string) * sizeof(char)));
```

should be

```
        arr_of_strings[l] = malloc(((strlen(temporary_string)+1) * sizeof(char)));
```

Comment: That's a BIG string.

Comment: @AdrianMole But there may be bigger string...

Comment: The suggestions do stop the segmentation fault, and I did get a const of MAX_LEN so I've used it as you suggested - the program does enter the function now (it's still acting weird but I'll take a look at that), thank you!